# В чем разница между Completion Handlers и Promises?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Сабж. И еще, что лучше использовать `Promises` или нотификейшн ивентбусы по типу дефолтного `NSNotificationCenter`. Использую в данный момент библиотеку SwiftEventBus. Наткнулся на Swift Bolts, и вот теперь думаю, стоит ли переводить на него проект.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Даже не знаю как на это ответить...

1) разница между completion handler и promise:

оба выполняют одну и ту же функцию - не блокировать выполнение приложения, пока идет обработка чего либо (например запроса к серверу, базе данных или любой другой алгоритм который по какой то причине занимает много времени). В случае с completionHandler вы задаете анонимную функцию, которая должна выполниться, когда обработка закончена; в другом случае, вы создаете прокси объект, который будет заменен на настоящий объект, когда обработка закончится. Какой лучше использовать? Я бы сказал единственный случай, где promise имеет смысл, это если вам надо передавать прокси объект между классами, короче говоря, если что то физическое должно присутствовать в приложении, пока запрос обрабатывается.

2) Что лучше использовать promises или notification?

Нотификейшн надо использовать только, если надо делать бродкаст, т.е. есть несколько объектов ожидающих нотификейшн, и эти объекты понятия не имеют об объекте который постит нотификейшн. Во всех остальных случаях должен использоваться completionHandler (или делегат, или другой традиционный способ). Так же подумайте о бедных девелоперах, которые будут после вас ковыряться в этом коде - блоки гораздо легче читать и понимать, чем notifications/promises.

3) Надо ли использовать случайно найденную в интернете библиотеку, которая круто выглядит?

Конечно! Вот всего несколько плюсов:

- Вы решите проблему, которая никогда не существовала.
- Другие разработчики, которые эту библиотеку никогда не видели, будут думать, что вы просто бог разработки.
- Вы скорее всего будете единственным человеком в компании, который может в этом разобраться, значит вас точно никогда не уволят.
- Вы потратите несколько недель, ковыряясь в крутых технологиях, и по фигу, что релиз выйдет позже, чем планировалось.

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее за такой развернутый ответ! Все как надо, все по полочкам. Спасибо.

Comment: Добавлю один вопрос. А цепочка из Completion Handlers (3 - 4 метода ожидающие выполнения друг друга) это нормально?

Comment: спорный вопрос. 2 мне кажется допустимо. 4 это уже надо задаться вопросом не пора ли пересмотреть архитектуру

Comment: Еще раз огромнейшее спасибо. Вы ответили на каждый мой вопрос, очень вам благодарен!